# Upgraded Shoulda from 2 to 3, and now my custom extended methods don't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, shoulda

My methods :

```
      Shoulda::Context.send(:include, Module.new do
        def when_reminder_sent(n, &blk)
          context "when reminder #{n} was sent" do
            setup { subject.free_trial_notice_sent = n }
            blk.bind(self).call
          end
        end
        def when_payment_was_received(&blk)
          context 'when payment has been received' do
            setup { subject.last_payment_received_at = 1.day.ago }
            blk.bind(self).call
          end
        end
      end)
```

It injects and returns true. So I know its in there. But when I do :

```
      context 'on day 15' do
        when_reminder_sent(15) { should('be nil') { assert_nil subject.reminder_to_send }}
```

It returns :

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `when_reminder_sent' for EnterpriseRegistrationTest:Class
```

Ah so I see its trying to use this method on my tested Model.. how can I ensure that it is using the method within its original Shoulda context?

*edit : fixed some typos *

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/bin/ps) is setuid or setgid
/Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@website/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@website/gems/shoulda-context-1.1.6/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:474:in `method_missing': undefined method `when_reminder_sent' for EnterpriseRegistrationTest:Class (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/elephanttrip/Sites/website/test/unit/enterprise_registration_test.rb:578:in `block (5 levels) in <class:EnterpriseRegistrationTest>'
  from /Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@website/gems/shoulda-context-1.1.6/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:322:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@website/gems/shoulda-context-1.1.6/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:322:in `merge_block'
```

Comment: Two things: are you sure that's the correct line of the error? Method names are case sensitive, and it looks like you've got a capital S somewhere. Also, you're missing a } on that line that you posted.

Comment: Ah ok I noticed that. Those were just innapropriate typos I made when rewriting it. My apologies. Just updated that. I posted the full stack as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just rewrote this and threw it at the beginning of the test. Evidently this module injection isn't properly coded for the upgrade.

**Winning Answer**

```
class MyMassiveObjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def self.when_reminder_sent(n, &blk)
    context "when reminder #{n} was sent" do
      setup { subject.free_trial_notice_sent = n }
      blk.bind(self).call
    end
  end
  def self.when_payment_was_received(&blk)
    context 'when payment has been received' do
      setup { subject.last_payment_received_at = 1.day.ago }
      blk.bind(self).call
    end
  end
```